# How to prove this inequality $(y^2 + m)^n > (x^n + y^n)^2$, by induction for n and m

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Anyone could help me to prove the following question?.

Assume that $x$, $y$, $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers such that $y>x$, $m=s^2 + 2sy$ for s natural number and $n>2$. Prove that

$$(y^2 + m)^n > (x^n + y^n)^2$$

I was trying to prove it by induction for n and m, and using only the conditions about y, m and n, but I can not get it at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your edit is a much better title but does not respond to my statement that the statement is false.  I don't know which came first.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  The left side is $(y+s)^{2n}$.  The most challenging case is $s=1$, which makes the left $(y+1)^{2n}$.  Now if $x$ is close to $y$ would be asking $(y+1)^{2n} \gt (x^n+y^n)^2 \approx (2y^n)^2=4y^{2n}$  For a specific counterexample, take $y=10,x=9,s=1,n=3$  Then we are asking that $11^6 =1771561\gt (9^3+10^3)^2=2989441$